# Can i create a new root user with root priviliges when i have just access to the boot partition?

Tags: linux, docker

is there any way i can create a new root user when i have just access to the boot partition.

I have no access to / partition . This is just a question for my own lap. So don't worry.

I running an alma-linux container with privileged mode and systemed on it  with sshd and apache installed and working.

Because docker fixed a lot of unsave things in the past, removing  CAP_SYS_ADMIN and so on, i find no way breaking into my host machine except modifying the boot partition.

Or someone else have an idear what i can do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is only one `root` user, `root`. Are you asking if you can add a new `sudo` user to `sudoers`?

Comment: No i'am asking if i can add sudo user if i just have access to the /boot paritition or is there any exploit i can do to gain root access to the system via the /boot partition ? using  AlmaLinux9